# Topological Invariance in Data Structures

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quiver, data-structure, topological-data-analysis

I need to do a PhD in Pure Mathematics and I am thinking of Topological Data Analysis. I want to use persistent homology and quiver representation to obtain topological features in data structures. Now, what kind of data structures can I use? Note that I need to come up with theorems and proofs, being a Pure Mathematics degree. It's not just about coding and coming up with persistence diagrams and barcodes.

Comment: The first step in doing a PhD is to find a department to do it in, and then an advisor. You sound as if you’re planning to write a thesis all by yourself! As for the question, it doesn’t seem well enough thought out to begin work. Why should this be possible? What past work does it build on? “Need to do a PhD in Pure Mathematics” is also a rather confusing phrase to hear... you are aware you’re talking about how you’ll spend the next 3-6 years of your life, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at Steve Oudet's publications? (See his [website](https://geometrica.saclay.inria.fr/team/Steve.Oudot/).)

Note that he has written one book and coauthored another that could be of interest to you:

Steve Oudot. *Persistence Theory: From Quiver Representations to Data Analysis*. AMS Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, volume 209, 2015.

F. Chazal, V. de Silva, M. Glisse, S. Oudot. *The Structure and Stability of Persistence Modules*. Springer Briefs in Mathematics, 2016.